# Jquery tab processing image on load

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i am adding a processing image to tab load.

```
 $("#tabid").on('beforeload', function(event, ui) {
        $("#maskDiv").css("display", "block");
    }).on('load', function(event, ui) {
        $("#maskDiv").css("display", "none");
    });
```

My all tab href has external page url, and content of tab is loading from this external url.
On above code mask is hiding before content ready. I want mask to be in page till content of tab ready.

Comment: Please provide your HTML code.

Comment: Please provide jsfiddle